# Moving items in array to another array. The error I get is 'Expected identifier'

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer

I have this code that works everywhere but IE. Not sure how to fix.

I need to remove an item from one array and then put it into the top of another array.

I currently have an array of articles a few of these articles have type hero is true and the others are just regular. I need to find the first hero article in the array and remove it. Then put this article into the top of another array.

The error I get is 'Expected identifier'

```js
const articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true},
];

const heros = [];

for (var [i, article] of articles.entries()) {
  if (article.hero) {
    heros.unshift(article);
    articles.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(heros);
console.log(articles);
```

Comment: [`Object.entries` isn't available in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Neither is destructuring and `of` `[i, article] of articles.entries()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries#Browser_compatibility

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

simple for loop works best for IE browser.

```js
const articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true},
];

const heros = [];

for(let i=0;i<articles.length;i++){

  if(articles[i].hero)
    {
    heros.unshift(articles[i]);
    articles.splice(i, 1);
    break;
    }
}

console.log(heros);
console.log(articles);
```

Comment: There are more issues. See comments to question - already mentioning for..of

Comment: I checked in IE 11. It works if 'for of'  is replaced with 'for in' .

Comment: Also `for..in` should never be used with Arrays

Comment: yeah! you are right. my bad. simple for loop is good when working with IE. updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

- for..of [not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility)
- Array.entries [not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries#Browser_compatibility)
- Destructuring [not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility)

My version

```js
const articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true},
];

let heros = [];
let i = -1;
articles.some(function(article) { i++; return article.hero; })
if (i>=0) {
  heros.push(articles[i]); 
  articles.splice(i,1);
}

console.log(heros);
console.log(articles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```js
const articles = [
    {title: "article 1", hero: false},
    {title: "article 2", hero: false},
    {title: "article 3", hero: true},
    {title: "article 4", hero: false},
    {title: "article 5", hero: true},
    {title: "article 6", hero: false},
    {title: "article 7", hero: true},
];

const heros = [];

Object.keys(articles).forEach(function(article) {
  var value = articles[article];
  if (value != undefined && value.hero) {
    heros.unshift(value);
    articles.splice(article, 1);
  }
});

console.log(heros);
console.log(articles);
```